# Ajax not working with MvcPaging

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Currently I am using the MvcPaging nuget package that I retrieved from here: https://github.com/martijnboland/MvcPaging

My problem is that instead of replacing my element when I use the @Html.Pager helper.  It opens up the partialview in a new tab.

My goal is to have my QuickLinks section update via Ajax without a full page refresh.

This is my controller:

```
    private CasuallyProDb db = new CasuallyProDb();
    private const int DefaultPageSize = 7;

    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        int currentPageIndex = 0;
        var news = db.PostedNews.OrderBy(a=>a.NewsId).ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, DefaultPageSize);
        return View(news);

    }

    public ActionResult AjaxPage(int? page)
    {
        int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value - 1 : 0;
        var news = db.PostedNews.OrderBy(a => a.NewsId).ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, DefaultPageSize);
        return PartialView("_QuickLinks", news);
    }
```

This is my index view that renders the partial view:

```
@model IPagedList<CasuallyPro.Models.News>
@using MvcPaging
<div id="quickLinksWrapper" class="float-right">
    @Html.Partial("_QuickLinks", Model)
</div>
```

And this is my _QuickLinks.cshtml partial view:

```
@model IPagedList<CasuallyPro.Models.News>
@using MvcPaging

<div id="quickLinksDisplay">
<ul>
    @foreach (var news in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <img alt="" src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => news.CategoryIcon)"/>
            <div class="quickLinksTitle">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => news.Title)<br/>
                <span class="quickLinksDetails">
                    <span class="quickLinksUsername"> Posted by @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => news.PostedUserName)</span>
                    <span class="quickLinksDate"> on @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => news.PostedDate)</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
<div id="quickLinksPagedList">
    @Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount, new AjaxOptions
                                                                          {
                                                                            UpdateTargetId = "quickLinksWrapper"
                                                                          }).Options(o => o.Action("AjaxPage"))
</div>
```

I am looking at the sample project they provided and it looks like this should do it but unfortunately it just isn't working appropriately.  I have the script referenced in the head section of my _Layout.cshtml for unobtrusive ajax:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Solved, I am an idiot and didn't reference this: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>